# How to convert REGEX array to String array in Python Chatbot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, nltk

I have a Chatbot with interactive communication.I used nltk library.I have modified Chat class for necessary functions.I want to save session.However I did it.But when I print the list which has session record, just print different way from I expect.

```
Output : [<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='Hello'>, <re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='Fine,How are you'>, <re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='Thanks'>, <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='bye'>]
```

How can I convert this array to normal String array ? I just need

> match ='blah blah'

part.Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
l = [m.group(0) for m in matches]
```

where `matches` is the array of match objects you started with.

This will give you for `l`:

```
['Hello', 'Fine,How are you', 'Thanks', 'bye']
```